# Can't use an sql query in Form.Load

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, entity-framework

Im currently trying to get better at SQL and at the moment I'm working on a small Windows Forms program that interacts with a database. I'm using Entity Framework to accomplish this. I've just ran into a problem that I can't seem to solve on my own. I'm trying to populate a ListBox with items from a database table. To do this my intention was to access all entrys in a table during the Form.Load and then add them to the ListBox. The problem I've ran in to is that for some reason the SQL code doesn't seem to execute when I put it in the Form.Load function. It works as intended if I create a button and use it inside the click event, which is why I'm a bit confused. The code is as simple as this:

THIS WORKS:

```
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dbConnection db = new dbConnection();

        var heroes = db.Hero.SqlQuery("Select * from Hero").ToList();
    }
```

THIS DOESN'T WORK:

```
    private void AddMatchForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dbConnection db = new dbConnection();

        var heroes = db.Hero.SqlQuery("Select * from Hero").ToList();
    }
```

Comment: What do you do with "heroes" once you've got it?  As far as I can see it will be lost when it goes out of scope (unless you are missing some code)

Comment: What do you mean by "Doesn't work"? Are you getting some exception?

Comment: did you try to put a `breakpoint` on load evnt?

Comment: @Andrew In this small example, nothing. The thing is if I write something weird inside the SQL statement I should get an error, but I only get that error in the first example

Comment: Are you sure the  Load event is even called? Did you set up the event handler properly? To verify, either place a `breakpoint` or do `MessageBox.Show()`.

Comment: Probably most likely thing is that your click event isn't being fired then.  Have you confirmed that the event for the button points to the correct handler?  If so, have you, as suggested by others put a breakpoint on the click event?

Comment: @AndyKorneyev The SQL statement is never executed. When I just write a bunch of random characters in the SQL statement I should get an error but I only get that error in the first example

Comment: @WeSt Yes, I've added a breakpoint and the code is reached

Comment: Exceptions in _Load are silently swallowed in a 32bit app on 64bit windows whilst debugging, wrap in try/catch and see if there is an exception.

Comment: @AlexK. Ok, I added the try/catch and now I got the exception. So that explains that. The reason I did the test to force the error was beacuse the contents of the table wern't added to my ListBox, but I guess there is something wrong with something else in my code then.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL statement looks fine. But are you ever invoking AddMatchForm_Load? Just because you named it "_Load" does not mean that the form is actually bound to it. And even if you are, you aren't doing anything with your "heroes" variable. So it's just going away once you leave the AddMatchForm_Load method.

Comment: I've tried placing a break point and it does indeed get called. Other code I write in there works as intended. And in the small code snippet I provided I don't do anything, but I've tried added random characters in the SQL statement which should yield an exception but doesnt do so. If I add the same random characters in the click event I do indeed get that exception